# What does set up an environment in ubuntu mean?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, environment, ros

This is probably a simple question but I've seen it mentioned in answers a few times and don't fully understand it.

What does it mean to "set up an environment"? In the context where I am preparing to install a dependency in ubuntu, before I can call `sudo apt-get install roslaunch` what does calling `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` actually mean?

When I call that second line before trying to install stuff nothing in my terminal changes? Is that line supposed to return something within the terminal or does it just mean something in the background that I can't see has changed? And if that is the case what is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you do `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` it is to make your current shell session aware of ROS related packages. The `setup.bash` prepares your bash session (which you interact though the terminal) and makes it aware of ROS-related tools (their locations, paths to Python etc).

For example, without running `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` when you want to invoke the `roslaunch` command to launch a package shell/bash won't be able to understand what `roslaunch` is, is the `setup.bash` that makes bash aware of `roslaunch`. Similarly, when you have a custom workspace (e.g., `catkin_ws`) you also need to source the `setup.bash` of that workspace!

Usually a good convention is to add this command in your `.bashrc`.